# Prime ideals in R[x] having the same contraction in R

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, polynomial-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $Q\subsetneq Q'$ primes in $R[x]$. If $Q'\cap R=Q\cap R$, then $Q=(Q\cap R)[x]$.

One inclusion is clear but I couldn't prove the other and I am not sure if the statement is true.

Comment: Do you mean $Q'=(Q\cap R)[x]$?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown No I mean $Q=(Q∩R)[x]$.

Comment: @user682705: Did you mean $Q\subset Q'$, i.e., _proper_ subset?

Comment: @quasi Yes $Q$ is a proper subset of $Q'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, equality holds.

Let $P=Q\cap R=Q'\cap R$.

The inclusion $P[x]\subseteq Q$ is immediate.

By Theorem 37 of the text

  Kaplansky -- Commutative Rings, 2nd Ed (1974)

there cannot exist a chain of three distinct prime ideals of $R[x]$ with the same contraction in $R$.

But $P[x]$ is a prime ideal of $R[x]$, hence, since we have the chain 
$$P[x]\subseteq Q\subset Q'$$
of three prime ideals of $R[x]$ with the same contraction in $R$ (namely $P$), it follows that the inclusion $P[x]\subseteq Q$ can't be proper.

Therefore $Q=P[x]$.

Comment: Thank you very much!